# meta-programming to parse json in scala

Tags: scala, metaprogramming, scalameta, treehugger

I need some hints to write a scala program that could read json file and create a case class at run time. As an example if we have json class like -

```
Employ{
    name:{datatype:String,  null:false}
    age:{datatype:Int,  null:true}
    Address:{city: {datatype: String, null:true}, zip: {datatype: String, null:false}}
}
```

and this should create class like

```
case class Employ(name: String, age: Option[Int], address: Address}
case class Address(city: Option[String], zip:String}
```

would it be possible to do it in scala?

Comment: So... you want to define classes dynamically at runtime. You can do it in scala but only after a very very good hold over the scala-reflection. My advice - avoid this approach unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: And then even after you are able to achieve this, you will again need good understanding of scala-reflection to use these classes and their instances.

Comment: This project tries to solve a part of your problem - https://github.com/julianpeeters/case-class-generator . You can consider yourself as being able to solve your problem only after all the code in this project looks as simple as english to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can easily achieve this using [TreeHugger](http://eed3si9n.com/treehugger/). I did a similar thing for one of my work projects.

Below is a toy example which produces a Scala Akka Actor class. It needs to be cleaned up but, hopefully, you get the idea:

```
import argonaut.Argonaut._
import argonaut._
import org.scalatest.FunSuite
import treehugger.forest._
import definitions._
import treehuggerDSL._

class ConvertJSONToScalaSpec extends FunSuite {

  test("read json") {

    val input =
      """
        |{
        |  "rulename" : "Rule 1",
        |  "condition" : [
        |    {
        |      "attribute" : "country",
        |      "operator" : "eq",
        |      "value" : "DE"
        |    }
        |    ],
        |  "consequence" : "route 1"
        |}
      """.stripMargin

    val updatedJson: Option[Json] = input.parseOption

    val tree =
      BLOCK(
        IMPORT(sym.actorImports),
        CLASSDEF(sym.c).withParents(sym.d, sym.e) :=
          BLOCK(
            IMPORT(sym.consignorImport, "_"),
            DEFINFER(sym.methodName) withFlags (Flags.OVERRIDE) := BLOCK(
              CASE(sym.f DOT sym.methodCall APPLY (REF(sym.mc))) ==>
                BLOCK(
                  sym.log DOT sym.logmethod APPLY (LIT(sym.logmessage)),
                  (IF (sym.declaration DOT sym.header DOT sym.consignor DOT sym.consignoreTID ANY_== LIT(1))
                    THEN (sym.sender APPLY() INFIX ("!", LIT(sym.okcm)))
                    ELSE
                    (sym.sender APPLY() INFIX ("!", LIT(sym.badcm)))
                    )
                )
            )
          )
      ) inPackage (sym.packageName)    
}
```

Essentially all you need to do is work out how to use the TreeHugger macros; each macro represents a specific keyword in Scala. It gives you a type-safe way to do your meta-programming.

There's also [Scala Meta](http://scalameta.org/) but I haven't used that.

Comment: His requirement can not be solved using Scala-macros as these macros work at compile time. What he need is ability to define new classes at runtime to fit the JSON structure which will be available at run time only. And the only thing that can help at runtime is reflection.

Comment: Yes, he can achieve that. The JSON can be parsed and converted into the class file using TreeHugger (he need to make sure that the compiler library is accessible). Once he has the text representation, he can compile that dynamically, and use the class loader to load the generated class.

Comment: If you believe that treehugger can help in generating and then instantiating unknown classes at runtime, I think you have some wrong idea about treehugger. Treehugger helps you in creating `scala-code strings` at run-time, nothin more. Your only hope will be to somehow get hold of the interpreter from the runtime and somehow use that to interpret the `code-string` but even that is very unlikely to work.

Comment: I'm not saying TreeHugger will compile the class. It will help him to generate the definition.

Comment: @tesnik03, once you have the definition produced, then use the toolbox module in the scala reflect library to compile the generated class definition and then use normal class loading techniques to load that class into the JVM.

Comment: @M.K. Very interesting! From this piece of code I do not have clear how do you generate the tree from the JSON string. Do you have an example of how to convert a JSON Actor into Scala code?

Answer (score 2):

Well... lets say you used some library like `treehugger` or `scala meta` or something else to generate the code string for case class. Now there are multiple approaches that you can take. To start with one of them, you can do the following.

```
// import the current runtime mirror as cm
import scala.reflect.runtime.{currentMirror => cm}

// you case code string
val codeString = """
  case class Address(city: Option[String], zip:String)

  Address(Some("CityName"), "zipcode")
"""

// get the toolbox from mirror
val tb = cm.mkToolBox()

// use tool box to convert string to Tree
val codeTree = tb.parse(codeString)

// eval your tree
val address = tb.eval(codeTree)
```

The problem is that the `val address` will have type `Any`. Also the universe still does not know about type `Address` so you will not be able to do `address.asInstanceOf[Address]`.

You can solve this one by exploring things about `ClassSymbol` and `ClassLoader` and with enough luck may be able to solve many more issues that you will face by understanding more about how reflection works in Scala and Java. But that will be a high effort and no guaranty of success path.

Comment: i like it too. here is your bit :)